# Is there a way to find out which variables in a knockout model are currently bound to the DOM?

Tags: binding, knockout.js

Is there a way to get a list of variables in a knockout model that are currently bound to the DOM?

Alternatively, is there a way to query a variable and find out if changing it would lead to a change in the DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Knockout 1.3 beta](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/08/31/knockout-1-3-0-beta-available/), you can use `ko.dataFor(element)` to return the data that would be bound against the element at that level.

This means that if you had an object like:

```
var myObject = { id: 1, name: "Bob" }
```

and bound it to an element

```
<div id="myElement" data-bind="text: name"></div>
```

`ko.dataFor(document.getElementById("myElement"))` would return `myObject` and not just the name.

Prior to 1.3, inside of a jQuery Template, you can use [tmplItem](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmplitem/) to return this type of data.

There is not really a way to programmatically determine if changing an observable will specifically alter a certain element.